# How to manage startup applications from terminal

Tags: command-line, autostart

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. How to manage startup applications from terminal?

I have refered [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

I would like to know CLI method. I am not asking to create `.desktop` file.

Comment: The linked dupe is to *add* an application to Startup Applications. To *remove* from command line is easyer :). Please leave a comment if it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't want to add only script but also any applicatio to startup from terminal without creating `.desktop` for a particular app. Am I clear?

Comment: Hi Ravan, There is no difference between adding a script and an application to startup applications, bot are *commands*. Adding to Startup applications *is* creating a `.desktop` file. It is what Dash > Startup Applications does as well. Try and look what happens in `~/.config/autostart`.

Comment: thanks @Jacob I will report back in few minutes and I close it if I found solution in dup :)